# Could the same person be First Minister in Northern Ireland and Taoiseach in the Republic of Ireland?

Tags: northern-ireland, republic-of-ireland, ireland

In the [2022 Northern Ireland Assembly election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Northern_Ireland_Assembly_election), [Sinn Féin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinn_F%C3%A9in) increased their vote share from 27.9% to 29.0% and became (for the first time) the largest party, amidst a split in the unionist vote between DUP, UUP, and TUV (in total there are still more unionist than nationalist votes).  In the [2020 Irish general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Irish_general_election), Sinn Féin got the highest share of the vote (24.5%) and the second-highest share of the seats.  In [opinion polls for the next Irish general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Irish_general_election#Opinion_polls), Sinn Féin is currently (May 2022) polling at 34%, a 13-percentage-point lead over the number two, raising speculation that a future [Taoiseach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoiseach) will be from Sinn Féin as well.

Political issues aside (Stormont power-sharing partner may not like the idea), would it be legally possible for the same person to be both Taoiseach in Dublin and First Minister in Stormont?

Comment: There has been political dispute over "[double-jobbing](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-northern-ireland-60046090)", which has focused on a ban on people being both members of the Assembly and Westminster parliament. I can't find if there's an equivalent ban on being in both the Northern Ireland Assembly and Irish parliament.

Comment: Isn't this a little like asking if someone can be President/Prime Minister of two countries at the same time?  I imagine the answer would be the same for *any* two countries, even if they're as closely linked as the two Irelands.  Or really, any two political offices even in the *same* country, not necessarily just heads of state.  You can't be a Governor of two different states in the US, for example.  Or Mayor + Senator in the same state, etc.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The unique aspect here is that the same party may end up providing the prime minister in both countries, and that party wants both countries to be one.  That makes it different from an arbitrary "can one person rule two countries".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, under [Section 19A](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/47/section/19A) of the Northern Ireland Act 1998, as amended by the  [Disqualifications Act 2000](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/42/section/2) and the [Northern Ireland (St Andrews Agreement) Act 2006](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/53/schedule/5/paragraph/3), which states that "No person may be nominated to hold the office of First Minister [...] if he is the holder of a disqualifying office". 'Disqualifying office' is defined in paragraph 4 of that section as including a "Minister of the Government of Ireland", which includes the Taoiseach.

Paragraph 2 of the section covers the situation whereby a First Minister were to become the Taoiseach:

> A Minister or junior Minister ceases to hold that office on becoming the holder of a disqualifying office.

Comment: I think this is only half the answer - it means someone who is already Taoiseach can't become First Minister, but doesn't cover whether the First Minister can become Taoiseach, or whether they would be required to resign if so.

Comment: @Bobson the act addresses this case - see update!

Comment: Yep, that covers it.  I figured there was probably something like that in there, because otherwise a nomination-only provision would be too big of a loophole.  Thanks for adding it!

Comment: A semi-interesting follow up would be the other angle: does the Dublin side have a similar rule, and what jobs would count there? E.g. can you be a minister of the government of Ireland, while at the same time holding some minor post in UK? (I know it's a different question, though, just thinking out loud.)

Comment: What I'm seeing here is that 1) The Taoiseach cannot be nominated for First Minister and 2) A First Minister loses their job upon becoming Taoiseach. As a programmer, this I immediately see the edgecase: What if a person is nominated for First Minister, and then becomes Taoiseach before being inaugurated (or whatever the term is) as First Minister? Technically, condition 1 no longer applies (they were already nominated) and the situation 2 did not occur (they weren't First Minister at the moment they became the holder of the disqualifying office).

Comment: As a fellow programmer @AI0867 think you're overlooking the main difference between a computer program and legal interpretation - the latter can use human judgement. The intent behind the law is clear and I doubt the edge case would be accepted as an exception by either the High Court in Belfast or the UK Supreme Court.

Comment: @AI0867 If you check out the standing orders of the NI assembly, the First Minister has to take the pledge of office and take up their role within 15 minutes of being nominated, so it would have to be a fairly speedy inauguration as Taoiseach! *Technically*, I guess it’s possible - *realistically*, not happening.

Comment: @ma499 I'm quite aware of the differences, I just enjoy poking holes in 'programs' or specifications written by non-programmers, even when the holes are irrelevant.